# Search results truncated

Tags: search

If I look at a normal list page on my blog (like frontpage), all the posts are displayed in full. When I search, the posts are truncated.

Is there a straight-forward way that I can make the search results page also display full posts?

Comment: Is this in the context of a theme or template you are developing? If so you'll need to share the code you are using to display search results. The likely answer is that you need to use `the_content()` instead of `the_excerpt()`. If you are asking as an end user then this a question you'll need to direct to your theme author, so you can find out if its an option for your theme.

Comment: That's very helpful. I'll check the theme content for that and see if I can make the change.

Comment: I'm trying but the change is not showing up. I disabled my cache plugin already.

Comment: OK. I got it figurd out. I had a shitter "wp-cache" plugin installed. I removed the plugin, which briefly broke my site… and then fixed it.